# Probability interpretation when operator spectrum not fully discrete or continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Consider the delta well. You have a bound state and scattering states.

Can I get a normalizable solution to the schrodinger equation that is some sort of a combination of the bound state and continuous states (maybe of the form bound state wave function + fourier integral for scattered states)?

Since even the bound state can be written as a linear combo of the scattered states, does this mean I can't interpret the fourier inverse transform as a probability density? Because if I could, then that would imply the bound state can give a range of positive energies, which makes no sense.

In general, can I get normalizable solutions to the schrodinger equation that are combos of bound states and scattered states? What is the probability interpretation then?

Note, the delta well has a half discrete/ half continous spectrum, which is where the issue of interpretation arises. (for discrete, I have orthonormality that explains interpretation and for totally continuous, I have dirac orthonormality).

Comment: This is more of a physics question. So, I think you will get more answers on Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I did that already, and I didn't get any answers, which is why I was hoping for someone with a basic physics background who would know about this to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Hydrogen isotope has bound states with energies that cluster around a point, beyond which there are only unbound states. Any complete expansion requires both the bound eigenstates as well as the unbound. The bound states are summed with an ordinary sum, and the unbound states are summed with an integral and a denstity function. Combining these two allows you to represent any state.

Comment: Yes, but then what is the probability interpretation? The density function alone will not be the probability density, because if it were, then the bound state contribution won't be accounted for. And physically, what does it mean for a particle to have bound and unbound contributions?? How can something be found in a bound state inside the atom at some point and then escape at a different time of measurement?

Comment: @childishsadbino : What do you mean by "The density function alone will not be the probability density..." I'm not sure that I'm clear on that. For each set of principal quantum numbers, there is a discrete set of energies that cluster from below toward $0$, and a continuum of states corresponding to positive eigenvalues associated with unbound states. These distributions change with the principal quantum numbers. This is the Schrodinger model of Hydrogen as I understand it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is this: let us say I can write a function as a linear combination of the discrete eigenstates. Then the probability interpretation states that the absolute value of the coefficients of these eigenstates are the probabilities of measuring a certain energy, provided these eigenstates are normalized. Similarly, if I write it as an integral "linear combination" of the continuum states, then the function that is being multiplied with the continuum states in the integral (the density function) is the probability density of measuring energies.

Comment: But if I have a state that is a combination of bound and continuum states, how do I attach a probability interpretation to such a state?

Comment: @childishsadbino : A probability measure $\mu$ can have discrete and continuous components.

Comment: May I ask how that would work? I have no background in measure theory, and this question is inspired from an introductory QM class I'm taking. Do you happen to know if there is a standard way to assign probabilities to wave functions of this sort when the spectrum is neither fully continuous nor discrete?